# Basic Python Counter

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, counter

I'm just a beginner with python guys. Python 3
This is my lab assignment:

Functions and while Loops. 
Create a main function that tests the specified function

summation (value)
This function returns the summation of 1 to value. You can assume that value will be positive.
For example, summation (5) would return 15 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5).

It gives me:     `print("Summation:",summation(10))`

So far I have

```
def summation (value):
    num = 1
    while num <= value:
        num = num + 1
    return value
```

I'm positive this is wrong but I don't know how to do it. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Well all you're doing here is changing `num` and then returning `value` unchanged.

Comment: I realize that, but I've never made a counter before and I don't know how to show a counter from, let's say, 0-10.

Comment: Very close, you'll want to define and keep track of a sum, and then return that instead of `value`.

Comment: Your counter is correct, you just need another variable to hold the running sum.

Answer (score 2):

What is the limit that value is representing?  The number of items in the sequence that you'll be adding.

What things do you need to keep track of while you're looping?  The sum of all the numbers so far, which number you're on now, and when you're done looping.

What do you need to do on each iteration of the loop?  Add the current number to the total and advance the current number to the next number in the sequence.

What do you have when the loop is done?  The last 'current' number and the sum so far.

Comment: Can someone just give me an example of a basic counter? Maybe that is where I need to start. I'm so lost!

Comment: This is the only answer I'm upvoting in this question because it actually attempted to teach the OP something.

Comment: I'd much much rather learn how to do this than to just get the answer. But I think in this case, the answer showed me what I was missing and then it made sense. Thank you all for your input though.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, what you're asked to do is code something that produces an equivalent result to the python built in function `sum`, applied to a `range`, `sum(range(1, value+1))`. Here, range returns all values between 1 and value and sum then adds them up.

You can do something similar:

```
def summation(value):
    i = 1
    sum_value = 0
    while i <= value:
        sum_value = sum_value + i
        i = i + 1 
    return sum_value
```

Comment: Despite this looking like it might work, I, personally try to avoid giving the complete answer to people who are doing homework but instead give them guidance.  Definitely not a rule around here, but I can't give it an upvote :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
def summation(n):
    count = 0
    num = 0
    while count < n:
        count+=1
        num+=count
    return num

print summation(5)
```

this will print `15`

i used a while loop that will only loop while the loop count is less than the original number then i used another variable that adds up to get the summation

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that's a little more Pythonic, including a main for testing:

```
import sys

__author__ = 'Michael'


def summation(n):
    return sum(x for x in range(1, n+1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994802/basic-python-counter"""
    n = int(sys.argv[1])
    print summation(n)
```

Comment: Way too complex.. `sum(range(1,x+1))` is all you need.